# value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm new on spark and I have faced with an issue.

When I run the code below on VM instance on Google Cloud Platform:

`val activationDF = kafkaDF.select(from_json($"value".cast("string"), activationSchema).alias("activation"))`

I have faced seen this error:

`error: value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader`

I have already import
`import org.apache.spark.sql.types._`
I also tried
`org.apache.spark.sql._`
but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it would be useful to see how you're creating `kafkaDf`, but I think I can infer what's going on here.

As the error message says, `select` is **not** a member of `DataStreamReader`, `select` **is** a member of `DataFrame` or `Dataset`. So you're probably calling `select` before calling the `load()` function that returns the `Dataframe` object that you want.

Here's an example of what I think is going on:

```
  val kafkaDF: DataStreamReader = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("options", "etc")
  kafkaDF.select() // Select is not a member of DataStreamReader this fails
  kafkaDF.load().select("Columns") // Now this works, because load() returns a Dataframe and you can select from it
```

Comment: Dear Riccardo,

Thank you for the reply. I guess the problem is caused by starting scala with just spark-shell , without required declarations.  

When I start scala with `spark spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2` it worked like a charm. 

Thanks for your explanation anyway.